# httppost action in mvc

Tags: routes, attributes, asp.net-mvc-5

i'm working on a MVC project and i used Controller from below code for registering the messages but i have a problem with it. When i execute the code, it cannot find contact page but when i comment [httppost] it can load contact page, in what step did i do a mistake? 
Thank you

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("Contact")]
    public ActionResult Contact(Contact msg)
    {
        try
        {
            Contacts.InsertMessage(msg);
            return View(model: "Successful");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View(model: "Failed:   " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another actionResult for loading the contact page like this?

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
   .....
}
```

If yes then it makes sense because when you assign [HttpPost] to a ActionResult the ActionResult will only handle POST requests (eg. submitting a form) and the one you use to load contact page doesn't have [HttpGet] which will handle GET requests. So, the controller won't know which ActionResult to process unless you place [HttpPost] or [HttpGet] or both at their respective ActionResult.